# Python: How do I put a list comprehension in a join function?

Tags: python, join, list-comprehension

How do I put a list comprehension in a join function

I ran this:

```
q = 1283634
print(f'{" ".join([str(q)[i:i+3] for i in range(len(str(q)),0,3)])}')
```

and printed

```
>>>
```

but I expected to print

```
>>> 1 283 634
```

Can someone explain what I did wrong?

Comment: Why is your join inside an f-string? Also, your range is way off. Starting from the length of q up to 0 in steps of 3 will yield 0 iterations, hence the empty string.

Comment: `range(start, stop[, step])`, you have `range(7,0,3)`, which will always result in no output. You probably mean `range(0, len(str(q)), 3)` which would result in `range(0,7,3)`.

Comment: A simpler approach would be to make use of f-string formatting, like `print(f'{q:,}'.replace(',', ' '))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your range is wrong. You are using the length of `str(q)` as the start value and and 0 as the end value. You should do the opposite: `range(0, len(str(q), 3)`. If you wish to iterate backwards, you can use a negative step: `range(len(str(q)), 0, -3)`

Remember that `range` has the form: `range(start, stop, step=1)`, where start is the starting index, stop is the ending index and step is optional and is the increment in index.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
q = 1283634
       #Joining    # First number   # Rest of number in pair of 3
print(" ".join(   [str(q)[0]]  +   [str(q)[i:i+3] for i in range(1, len(str(q)), 3)]))
```

Output

```
1 283 634
```

---

Or you can use this way

```
q = 1283634

formatted_q = "{:,}".format(q).replace(",", " ")
print(formatted_q)
```

Output

```
1 283 634
```

Here `"{:,}".format(q)` will return a formatted string like this `"1,283,634"` and then using `replace` method I am just replacing the "," with an space " ".